# My thread Stops

Tags: c++, multithreading, matrix

My problem is that I am starting a Thread to read data from my EyeTracker. I start it using the following functions:

```
BlinkMode::BlinkMode()
{
 bBlink = false;
 threadStopped = true; 

 recordeddata = nullptr;

 gT = GazeTracker::getGazeTracker();
 canRecord = false;  
 numCameras = gT->getNumCameras();
 if( numCameras >0){
     canRecord = true; 
 }

 filename = "blinkmode.txt";
 counter = 0;
 calipointno = 0 ; 
}

void BlinkMode::startRecording()
{
if (!bBlink)
{
    // Turn thread loop signal on
    bBlink = true;
    bBlinkSuccess = false;  
    bExcessData = false;    
    blinkThread = std::thread(createBlinkThread, this);
}
}

void BlinkMode::createBlinkThread(void* instance)
{
  BlinkMode* pThis = (BlinkMode*) instance;
  pThis->bBlink;
  if(pThis->canRecord){
     pThis->threadStopped = false;
     pThis->BlinkModeThread();
     pThis->threadStopped = true;
}
}

void BlinkMode::BlinkModeThread ()
{
BlinkMode* pThis = (BlinkMode*) this;
pThis->bBlink;

Matrix mProvData = Matrix (DR_DATAANALYSIS, GT_EYEDATALENGTH);
Matrix aSourceMatrix = Matrix (DR_MAXRECORDEDDATA, GT_EYEDATALENGTH);
recordeddata = new float[DR_MAXRECORDEDDATA][GT_EYEDATALENGTH];


while(bBlink){

    if(counter<DR_MAXRECORDEDDATA){
        gT->getCurrentData(recordeddata[counter],ALLDATA);
```

[ETC ...]

The thing is that my boolean bBlink, which is defined as a private volatile boolean in the header file of my class:

```
class BlinkMode
{

private:

// Monitor thread control signal.
volatile bool bBlink;}
```

becomes false right after the creation of the Matrix instances, (Matrix is another class of my code). And hence, the while loop is NEVER entered. However, if I comment the Matrix lines, it works! I can even execute the new float "recordeddata", but not the Matrices.

Does that mean that I cannot call another classes while I am inside a Thread or something? Sorry I am pretty new with C++ and I am lost.

Any help please??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you should provide the code from the Matrix function aswell. I also dont understand what the sense of `BlinkMode* pThis = (BlinkMode*) this;
pThis->bBlink;` is here... You could be a victim of undefined behaviour here

Answer (score 0):

The Matrix class is just to initialize Matrices in different ways and do operations with them, kind of like this:

```
class Matrix
{
public:
// Default constructor
Matrix();
// Default destructor
~Matrix();
// Initialise matrix of rows x cols.
Matrix(const int rows, const int cols);
// Convert a two dimensional array (rows x cols) of integers to a matrix.
Matrix(const int* const* num, const int rows, const int cols);
// Convert a two dimensional array (rows x cols) of floats to a matrix.
Matrix(const float* const* num, const int rows, const int cols);
// Copies the required row into the array.
void getRow(const int row, double[]) const;
// Copies the required row into the matrix.
void getRow(const int row, Matrix&) const;
// Sets the values of a row to the values of the array.
void setRow(const int row, const int[]);
enter code here
```

So I am just creating 2 objects there, and that is when the boolean automatically changes to false!!
I just created the pThis pointer you mentioned to be able to access the value of the boolean and check when it changes, but it is not relevant for the code... I can erase it and nothing changes...